# MRR build for GDAL version 3.7

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, multi-resolution-raster

Precisely provide MapInfo MRR Raster SDK Binaries and GDAL plugin for QGIS (https://support.precisely.com/product-downloads/item/mapinfo-mrr-sdk-download/), however the plugins are specific to specific GDAL versions. They also provide instruction on how to compile for other GDAL versions. I have tried following their "simple" instructions but they are well and truly beyond my capabilities. I am currently running QGIS version 3.32.0 Lima, with GDAL 3.7.0 and PROJ 9.2.1 on Windows. Has anyone been able to follow their "simple" instructions and compile for GDAL 3.7?